# How to call the amount an element in a list fits a criterium?

Tags: python, linear-regression, p-value

In Python, I am trying to print the amount that p-value is smaller than 0.05 (for 100 random p-values). The p-value itself is the slope element of a linear regression which I also called.

I currently have the following code: As a result I get an error message. I know why this occurs but just don't know any other way to print the amount of p values which fit my criterium.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
from scipy.stats import linregress

def func():
    a = 0
    x = np.random.rand(100)
    y = np.random.rand(100)
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = linregress(x, y)
    return  slope, intercept, p_value, x, y

a = 0
for i in range(100):
    myfunc= func()
    p = myfunc[3] #[3] assigning p to the p_values
    if p[i] < 0.05:
        a += 1
    print(len(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

Report the error you are getting

Note that the p value is the third element returned by func.  You want index 2 not 3.  You want p, not p[i] in the comparison.  'a' is an integer that does not have a length.  .  In any case you want to print a, not len(a) and you want to do so outside the loop.

Note the p value is not the slope, though the two are related.

Comment: The error message I got was
"object of type 'int' has no len()"
Like you said, I changed the index to 2 instead of 3 (I was looking at the elements of linregress instead of what I returned from the function). Also fixed the error by not printing the lenght of a and place the print statement of a outside the loop seems to work. Thanks a lot!